# How to fix th row Issue in table

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table

I have a `tr th` row that isn't displaying properly because I have a `div` containing my rows of data after. Right now the Table header looks like the following because of the div in my table. This is all inside a React component.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
        <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
                <th>D</th>
                <th>E</th>
                <th>F</th>
              </tr>
             { list.map((a, index) => {
             return( 
             <div className="coinrow"  onClick={goToPage}>
                <tr key={a} className="styledtr">
                    <td rowspan="2">A</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">A</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td style={{width: 150}}>
                        A
                        <Sparklines data={volchart}>
                            <SparklinesLine color="blue" />
                        </Sparklines>
                    </td>

                    <td style={{width: 150}}>
                        A
                        <Sparklines data={chart}>
                            <SparklinesLine color="blue" />
                        </Sparklines>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr key={a} className="styledtr">
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td style={{width: 150}}>
                        A
                        <Sparklines data={freqs}>
                            <SparklinesLine color="blue" />
                        </Sparklines>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </div>
            )
        })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

The first element is aligned far to the left. I tried changing the width manually and this didn't work. How can I fix this formatting issue?

Comment: `{ list.map((a, index) => {` is not a part of HTML syntax...

Comment: It's react js HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can use `style="width:150px"`
Or
You can also use this attribute directly instead of giving inside style tag.
Like this `width="150px"`
Also you have not used any vw, vh, or px with your width number that's why Its not applying on rest.

Comment: I tried manually setting the width and this doesn't work